# MonoDevelop Exclude a folder from SVN

Tags: svn, directory, monodevelop

Is there a way to tell a MonoDevelop project to exclude from source control a folder in the project. The folder has large SQLite databases I don't need/want published.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Dont know much about MonoDevelop but you jsut need to set the `svn:ignore` for the file in question on the folder containing it. With the command line client it would look like

`svn propset svn:ignore filename.db /path/to/folder`